# Multiple method cycle reflux store

Tags: socket.io, reactjs, koa, refluxjs

Does anyone know the complete sequence of reflux methods? I have this reflux store and its relation shown in the flow below:

`component =(listen state)=> store =(listen)=> action =(listen trigger)=> component`

That is the complete cycle, and I am trying to integrate this into `socket.io`

Code snippet:

Store:

```
export default Reflux.createStore({

  listenables: [action],

  init() {
    this.state = messages;
    this.registerListener();
  },

  registerListener() {
    msgSocket.on('message', (user, msgs) => {
      this.state.msg.push(`${user} : ${msgs}`);
      this.trigger(this.state);
    });
  },

  getInitialState() {
    return this.state;
  },

  onSendMessage(username, message) {
    msgSocket.emit('message', username, message);
  }

});
```

But I get this result:

```
[user: undefined,
user: myMessage]
```

Why does it seem its repeating? anyone knows?